# How to do MySQL Transaction over two different servers with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions

I am making a winform application in c#. I need to update/insert or delete two **different tables** in **two different databases** on two **different servers** and I want to do it with transaction (If update in one database fails, the other will be rolled back.)

How can I do it, please give some code in c# and also state whether it is good to do mysql transaction over two different servers (I mean, is there any chances that database will get corrupted by poor implementation of distributed transaction as I read this in some forum).

I searched over internet but I could not find c# code.

Thank you

Comment: not possible. transactions are per-server, and per-connection as well. you cannot have two connections to two servers and have ONE transaction. you'll have TWO transactions: one on each server.

Comment: Get your app working with one MySQL database first. If you are using C# make sure you download and add references for the MySQL connectors: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html

If you really need a 2nd database, setup MySQL master/slave replication.

Comment: we do this with XA and 2 phase commits for financial firms. fear not

Comment: Yes Drew Pierce. I want to know how to do XA 2pc in C# and Mysql..example.    Actual I am making a point of sale system. There will be 15 branches. At each branch, there will be a local server in the local branch office. At the end of day, Users will click a button and all entries of the day will be inserted in a Database on a BIG server connected through WAN and in local DB table, entries will be deleted or flagged as posted.

Obviously, This needs to be done in transaction.

Replication is not a good option because of some other factors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try using the TransactionScope class.

Simply wrap your two sql statements in a transaction scope and they should both commit or rollback together.

```
using(var transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    ... Add your transactional code here ...

    transaction.Complete();
}
```

I'm not sure this will work but it will give you a place to start and should be simple to test.

Comment: msdtc and mysql is a no-starter. it is like wrapping a gun in an envelope